How to fix the position of a figure which spans across two columns?
I'm using the following code to make a figure span across two columns:
\begin{figure*}[th]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
\caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}

However, the figure is not placed on the correct page when using the [th] specifier.
I tried using \begin{figure*}[H] with \usepackage{float}, but this didn't work either. also , using [H] with \begin{figure} does not span the figure across two columns. Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this issue?

Two column figures only support t or p placement, not h

figure* does not support h so [ht] is just preventing p being used, best to remove that option. They appear at the earliest on the following page, so if you want it to come earlier move it earlier in the source file.

if your figure is more than 70% of text height then \begin{figure*}[th] prevents it being placed at all (as it is too big for t and p is prevented by the option so that figure and all following figures will go to the end of the document

Also, figure* will never appear on the page where it is created.  You tyupically have to  insert it a page early and maybe futz the caption number.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720580/way-to-span-a-picture-table-across-all-columns-in-multicolumn-article-report-and/721028#721028
